# Asp.net core SSL could not run in docker container

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, docker-container

I have Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(301, 44339);
    app.UseRewriter(options);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    var localizedOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizedOptions.Value);

    app.UseIdentity();

     app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "LocalizedDefault",
            "{lang:lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "{*catchall}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", lang = "vi" });
    });
}
```

and

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel().UseUrls("https://*:443")
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

I used this cmd:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 1234:80 --name voiconshop_ps voiconshop
```

Here is ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
f752d350823b        voiconshop          "dotnet VoiConShop.d…"   About a minute ago   Up 59 seconds       0.0.0.0:1234->80/tcp    voiconshop_ps
```

And this is dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "VoiConShop.dll"]
```

I run http://localhost:1234/ then direct to https://localhost:44339/. However, the page return "This site can’t be reached".
So what did I do wrongly?
Please help me. Thanks you so much.
If need more information I will edit this question.

Answer (score 2):

I see multiple issues in your implementation.

1. I think running web app/service in HTTPs requires SSL certificate to be bound. Consider the below code snippet to replace .UseKestrel() in your code. Implement LoadCertificate method to return your SSL Certificate(X509Certificate2 object)

   ```
    .UseKestrel((options => { options.Listen(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 443),
                 listenOptions =>
                 {
                     var httpsConnectionAdapterOptions = new AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions()
                     {
                         ClientCertificateMode = AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.ClientCertificateMode.NoCertificate,
                         SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls,
                         ServerCertificate = LoadCertificate()
                     };
                     listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsConnectionAdapterOptions);
                 });
   ```
2. Add 443 port in dockerfile. It should look like

   Expose 80 443
3. We should also set "ASPNETCORE_URLS" Envionment Variable with "http://*:80/;https://*:443/" in docker-compose.override.yml.

   environment:

   - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
   - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:80/;https://*.443

   ports:

   - "80"
   - "443"

Comment: Could you post `LoadCertificate()` to here?

Comment: You can just use "return new X509Certificate2(certFilePath, certPassword)" in the method with certificate file(.pfx) path and its password.